# How to visualise open cones of infinite spaces?

Tags: general-topology

By open cone I mean the usual definition

$\mathcal{O}X = \frac{X \times [0, 1)}{X \times \{0\}}$.

I can view what an open cone will look like if $X = [0, 1]$, for example. Is there anyway of viewing what an open cone will be for larger spaces, such as $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$?

Are there any theorems which give us information about the open cone of $X$, given properties of $X$?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to the open interval $(-1;1)$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ can be 'squashed into' that interval via a function like:

$ f(0) = 0 $

$ f(n) = 1 - \frac{1}{n} $ if $n > 0$

$ f(n) = -1 - \frac{1}{n}$ if $n< 0$

The open cones of the images of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are simpler to visualize, in my opinion.

I don't think all the properties carry over, though - I think there might be a problem with local connectedness in the example for $\mathbb{Z}$, for example... What properties are you interested in?

Comment: I'm not interested in anything in particular, just interested to see if we can immediately deduce anything about the cone of $X$ just based on $X$. I'm fairly new to this, are you saying about that if there is a homeomorphism from $X$ to $Y$, then there is also a homeomorphism from $\mathcal{O}X$ to $\mathcal{O}Y$?